# Bayesian agreement

Tags: bayesian, agreement-statistics

Assume that there are k expert measuring some quality x with a number between zero and one, $x_i \in [0,1], i=1,2,...,k$. I would like to first know the aggregated quality of x with respect to the experts' opinions, and then I also want to know the extent to which the experts agree (or disagree).

To do so, I used the following model where x is the latent quality (similar to Kruschke, Chapter 9, Equation 9.4):

$ x_i \sim beta(x(k-2)+1,x(k-2)+1)$

where x is the mode of the beta, and $k>0$ is a constant. I know that the bigger value for $k$ means the more agreement between experts. But it does not show to what extent they agree.

Comment: What exactly is your data? Is it just $k$ measurements, one for each expert? How do you define agreement between the experts? It sounds like a small variance of the measurements, but without any other information or data it is rather hard to define what "small" means in here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, there k measurement, one for each expert. Let's say if all experts assign the same value, then there is full agreement.

Comment: Fast-and-dirty solution is to look how often do the experts differ by more then some $\varepsilon$.